# Trying to use getopt in C to write a program that pseudo-simulates -uniq of bash, need to represent input and output for filenames

Tags: c

The idea is for the code to print out certain options onto the screen as if it is reading -uniq from Bash's abilities on the command line.

Let's say I want to represent [input file] and [output file] for uniq, I set a default that would automatically set the opt on the command line to represent input and output along with the next argument on the command line.
However, my program effectively ignores its existence.

Also, I'm trying to represent fields properly with -f, if -f followed by a number was entered, I would get the number field ignored. However, the ascii to decimal value gets represented.

I tried to use atoi to turn the char into the number instead of letting the compiler auto translate.

For my efforts I was rewarded a segmentation fault.

Here is what I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
int opt;
char CASE_CODE = '0';
while((opt=getopt(argc, argv, ":'default'cduf:fs"))!= -1)
{
  switch(opt)
  {
    case 'c':
        CASE_CODE = 'c';
        break;
    case 'd':
        CASE_CODE = 'd';
        break;
    case 'u':
      printf("option : %c\n", opt);
        CASE_CODE = 'u';
        break;
    case 'f':
        int keyCODE = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
                if(i == optind)
                 keyCODE = argv[i][0];
                 printf("ignoring field: %d\n", atoi(keyCODE));
                  CASE_CODE = 'f';
        break;
    case 's':
        for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
                if(i == optind)
                        printf("the char to be ignored is %c ", argv[i][0]);
        CASE_CODE = 's';
        break;
    case ':':
      printf("Option %c needs a value \n", optopt);
        CASE_CODE = ':';
        break;
    case '?':
      printf("Unknown input detected %c\n", optopt);
        CASE_CODE = '?';
        break;
    default:
        if(strncmp(CASE_CODE, '0', 1));
                for(int i =0; i < argc; i++)
                if(i == optind)
                        printf("Input file : [%s], output file : [%s]", argv[i][0], argv[i+1][0]);
                break;

 }
}
 printf("\nCase code %c\n", CASE_CODE);
for(; optind < argc; optind++)
  printf("argument : %s\n", argv[optind]);
  exit(0);
```

```
Any advice?
```

Comment: The option string ":cdu:fs" says that `-f` is an option that takes no arguments, and `-u` is an option that *does* take an argument. Perhaps you meant ":cduf:s:"

Comment: Note that the arguments are all strings, and `optarg` is a `char *`, so you get a string pointing to the value associated with an option such as `-u xyz` or `-u 329` (you can't directly control what the user types; you have to validate it and reject that which is not valid). So, if you expect a number, you have to convert the string pointed at by `optarg` to an integer, and then you can print it with `%d`. If you expect the user to type `-u '12 34'` to get two numbers for one option, so be it; you'll have to make the correct usage clear — and parse the string value appropriately (`strtol()`?).

Comment: And if you want `--uniq` to be a single 'long' option, you'll probably need to use GNU [`getopt_long()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html#Getopt), or some similar argument parser.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't need uniq to be a single long option, I just need it to parse the string value and convert it to decimal. The problem is that when I do, I get a segmentation fault and my program closes.